# Problemas en conectar lel cliente en Redis

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, redis

Tengo creado así el cliente de redis. Pero al importarlo me sale pendiente
Es la v4 con lo cual tengo que conectarlo, según fuentes oficiales, Pero no consigo ver el error  He colocado return dentro de client, pero tampoco Son los archivos de crear cliente y dónde lo importo
El error que sale por consola es el último

````
const client = redis.createClient({
    url: `redis://default:${String(process.env.REDIS_PASS)}@localhost:${String(
        process.env.REDIS_PORT
    )}`,
});
//redis://default:fzG*aSD3@dsa5ssd@localhost:10912/ita_directory_redis`

client.on("error", (err) => console.log("Redis Client Error", err));

client.connect();

module.exports = {client};
 

---------
 const {client} = require("../utils/initRedis");
const signRefreshToken = async (userid, maxAge = 86400) => {
  console.log("### REFRESH TOKEN");
  const hashedId = hashids.encode(userid);
  const payload = {iss: "itacademy", sub: {user_id: hashedId}};
  const secret = process.env.JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET;
  const options = {expiresIn: maxAge};
  const token = JWT.sign(payload, secret, options);
  await client.set(userid, token); //falta opcions )
  return token;
};
----------
POST /users/v1/login 200 42.351 ms - 509
node:internal/errors:464
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received type number (2)
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:312:13)
    at Socket.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
    at RedisSocket.writeCommand (C:\Users\Otso\Desktop\itaproyect\ita-directory\backend\node_modules\@node-redis\client\dist\lib\client\socket.js:57:130)        
    at Commander._RedisClient_tick (C:\Users\Otso\Desktop\itaproyect\ita-directory\backend\node_modules\@node-redis\client\dist\lib\client\index.js:421:64)      
    at Commander._RedisClient_sendCommand (C:\Users\Otso\Desktop\itaproyect\ita-directory\backend\node_modules\@node-redis\client\dist\lib\client\index.js:402:82)
    at Commander.commandsExecutor (C:\Users\Otso\Desktop\itaproyect\ita-directory\backend\node_modules\@node-redis\client\dist\lib\client\index.js:160:154)      
    at Commander.BaseClass.<computed> [as set] (C:\Users\Otso\Desktop\itaproyect\ita-directory\backend\node_modules\@node-redis\client\dist\lib\commander.js:8:29)
    at signRefreshToken (C:\Users\Otso\Desktop\itaproyect\ita-directory\backend\app\utils\utils.js:67:9)
    at exports.login (C:\Users\Otso\Desktop\itaproyect\ita-directory\backend\app\controllers\users.controller.js:238:25) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'```
````

Comment: Ahemm.... Cuál es el problema? Mensaje de error? Logs? Qué es lo que dice la pestaña 'Network' en las herramientas de desarrollador? Redis recibe la comunicación?

Comment: @Arriel he puesto los errores que salen por consola al final

Comment: Por qué piensas que es redis? Ya buscaste el error en google?  Parece que estás enviando un número, cuando deberías estar enviando un `string` o `Buffer`, o `Uint8Array`